# How to fetch data from Fiware Cygnus?

Tags: fiware-cygnus, fiware-wirecloud, fiware-sth-comet

I have setup Cygnus with MySQL agent and now data is storing into MySQL server.

As a next step, we need to show reports of historical data (Saved in Cygnus_MySQL) in GUI. It may be based upon some filters like data for today, last week/month, area wise etc.

**My questions are**

1. Do we need to create our own APIs for fetching data from MySQL and returning to GUI application?
2. Or is there any GUI component (WireCloud or any other) in which we can directly fetch Cygnus Data? Or we need to create our custom GUI ourselves?
3. I found a component STH-Comet (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet), will it fit in our requirements for fetching Cygnus_MySQL data?
4. Do let me know if Fiware have any other components matching with our requirement.

Regards,

Krishan